# Get Timestamp from custom class

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've searched for two hours and I'm astounded there is no simple way for retrieving `Timestamp` from Firebase using custom class.

This is how document I'm retrieving looks like:

[image]

I have for this document simple custom class:

```
import com.google.firebase.Timestamp;

import java.util.List;

public class CapObj {
    private String content;
    private List<String> tags;
    private Timestamp created_at;

    public CapObj () {}

    public CapObj (String content, List<String> tags, Timestamp created_at){
        this.content = content;
        this.tags = tags;
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public List<String> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreatedAt() {
        return created_at;
    }
}
```

and I populate my list with this method:

```
private void populateDatasetFromQuery(Task<QuerySnapshot> task){

    ArrayList<Caption> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

        CapObj capObj = document.toObject(Caption.class);
        results.add(caption);
    }
    capObjList = new ArrayList<>(results);
}
```

So the problem is that when I try to use `capObj.getContent()` I get content, but when I do `capObj.getCreatedAt().toDate()` I get:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Date com.google.firebase.Timestamp.toDate()' on a null object reference`. even though the object I got from Firebase query looks like this:

`{created_at=Timestamp(seconds=1583017200, nanoseconds=0), content=Travel 2, tags=[travel]}`

To me it seems that `created_at` is not populated when object is created. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore doesn't know how to map the `created_at` field into your object.  What you should do is create a public setter method that matches the field:

```
public void setCreated_at(Timestamp timestamp) {
    created_at = timestamp;
}
```

Since you're using underscores in the field name, that makes for an ugly setter name (as is the convention for Java POJO), so you might want to give it a better name, and annotate it with [PropertyName](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/PropertyName) so that Firestore knows which field should be used to call that method:

```
@PropertyName("created_at")
public void setCreatedAt(Timestamp timestamp) {
    created_at = timestamp;
}
```

The general convention for all POJOs is to have matching public getters and setters with the same property name (e.g. getFoo/setFoo).

Comment: so I should use `createdAt` as a property name in Firestore database? I don't have much data there yet so I can change that if that will help - I thought underscore is preferred for db property names.

Comment: If that's what you prefer.

Comment: I prefer my code to be as clean as possible - and I can see you're more experienced so I was curious what makes more sense long term :)

And I'm not sure why, but it workes! I didn't make sense to me because i.e. `content` was set even though I don't have setter for that. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of timestamp, you can use timeinmillies and you also need to setter method:
You can do like this:

```
import java.util.List;

public class CapObj {
@SerializedName("content")
private String content;
@SerializedName("tags")
private List<String> tags;
@SerializedName("created_at")
private long created_at;

public CapObj () {}

public CapObj (String content, List<String> tags){
    this.content = content;
    this.tags = tags;
    this.created_at = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
}


public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public void setTags(List<String> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
}

public long getCreated_at() {
    return created_at;
}

public void setCreated_at(long created_at) {
    this.created_at = created_at;
}


public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public List<String> getTags() {
    return tags;
}


}
```

after getting data you can convert long to calendar date-time using below method:

```
Date getDateFromLong(long timeInMillis){
 Calendar time_date=Calendar.getInstance();
 time_date.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
 return time_date.getTime();
  }
```

Comment: Do I need a setter method when I just want to get timestamp from that object? I don't plan to send any values back to database.